# Strange residuals vs. fitted values plot for linear mixed model / hierarchical model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, residuals, random-effects-model, nested-models

I have read a couple of related questions and their answers, but nothing really fits to my specific case.

I have a model like this:

```
model <- lmerTest::lmer(
  Rating ~ Codition + Gender + Condition:Gender + (1|Study/ParticipantID), 
  data = ..., REML = TRUE, na.action=na.exclude)
```

So, all my predictors, fixed and random effects are factors.
Every person took part in 2 conditions, participants are nested in one of 7 studies.
N (participants) = 392.
Numer of observations = 784 (1 observation per condition per participant).

Using the model above I get this residual vs. fitted values plot, which shows some strange pattern but I can't tell why.

[image: Residual vs. fitted values]

If I remove the ParticipantID from the model, it looks a bit better (?), but Participant is nested within Study (repeated measurements design) so I have a reason to include it.

[image: Residual vs. fitted values]

Do you have an idea what is going on here?

Thank you!!

Comment: Start with two principles. (1) Observations with the same predictor values have the same fitted values, regardless of observed values of the outcome (vertical stripes). (2) Values with the same observed values follow diagonal lines that are residual $=$ CONSTANT $-$ fitted, so have slope $-1$.  In particular it seems that your lowest rating is $1$, so residual $= 1 - $ fitted is a lower bound to each plot.

Comment: With exactly 2 observations per individual, you might be able to use a simpler model. Just model the _difference_ between conditions for each individual as a function of gender and study (which you could treat as either fixed or random). That's a generalization of the paired t-test, and can handle the repeated-measures aspect more efficiently, provided that there isn't interest in differences of baseline values between genders or among studies.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you! The ratings range from 0 to 10 and there is 0 inflation (in condition 1 there are lots of zeros, in condition 2 the ratings are higher). Is the plot problematic in your opinion? Since the residuals differ for different fitted values...

Comment: @EdM Thank you! That does seem simpler indeed, but how can I argue that this is a generalization of the paired t-test. If my model is then `RatingDifferences <- Gender + (1|Study)` I have not included the variance/standard deviation of the participant like in a paired t-test or with `+(1|Study/ParticipantID)` or have I implicitly?

Comment: Clearly you are right that $-$ fitted is, literally, the bottom line. The plot is fine in principle but just needs to be interpreted bearing in mind the artefacts mentioned.

Comment: With a paired t-test and only 2 observations per participant there is no "variance of the participant." Each participant then has only 1 value submitted to the paired t-test, the _difference_ between her measurements.  That t-test approach won't work, however, if you want to model baseline values by gender or Study. If you do want to fit those baseline values with a mixed model, then @NickCox has pointed you toward an explanation of the "strange" plot that resulted.